# Using Matlab's sinc() in filter design?

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

In order to design a filter (windowing method), I first generate my sinc function, like so:

```
L = 20;
fc = 0.25;
n = (1:L)';
my_sinc = sin(2*pi*fc*(n-L/2)) ./ (pi*(n-L/2));            
my_sinc(L/2) = 2*fc;
```

Then I apply window:

```
win = blackman(L, 'symmetric');
filter_coeffs = (my_sinc .* win);
```

Can the first step be done using Matlab's builtin `sinc()` function?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: For this type of questions it is often useful to see the source code. Try `type sinc` in the command window and you'll see that the function does what it should

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. You can use the builtin [`sinc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sinc.html) function to get exactly the same result as what you have calculated in `my_sinc`. Since `sinc(x) = sin(pi*x)/(pi*x)`, in your case the input argument to the sin function, `x`, is equal to `2*pi*fc*(n-L/2)`. The denominator can then be written as a function of this `x` (`pi*(n-L/2) = 0.5*x/fc`) which gives you a scaling factor of `2*fc` multiplying the `sinc`. This can be illustrated here:

```
builtin_sinc = 2*fc*sinc(2*fc*(n-L/2));
hold off; stem(n, my_sinc);
hold on;  plot(n, builtin_sinc, 'rx');
```

[image]

You can then subsequently obtain the same filter coefficients with

```
filter_coeffs = (builtin_sinc .* win);
```

or directly

```
filter_coeffs = 0.5*sinc(2*fc*(n-L/2)) .* win;
```

Comment: Thanks. Here is a basic theory behind `sinc`: [Ideal Lowpass Filter](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Ideal_Lowpass_Filter.html).